# Robotframework - fatal error in listener should end suite run

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a python listener where, if a certain error is caught, I would like to stop executing tests immediately and instead end the suite. At the moment, I am doing this with `sys.exit()`, but this leads to no log file being produced a broken xml output, which is not ideal. I would still like the end-of-suite processes to run, I just want to skip running all subsequent tests.

I know when I ctrl-C a running test suite, every subsequent test is stopped with "Test execution stopped due to a fatal error". How can I trigger this safely in a listener when catching an exception?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Go with [Fatal Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Fatal%20Error) from the BuiltIn library - it'll do precisely that, fail all consecutive tests after its call.

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
BuiltIn().fatal_error('your message here')
```

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak Does this answer your question?